# UITableVIew appending data which is already present : swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

So I have a MainViewController in which I have a UItableView. I am getting the table data from firebase. **Now when I show any other viewController and then come back to the MainViewController using navigationController.popViewController(), the table again appends the previously present data. which doubles the data, if I visit again, it again adds the data and it triples.! and so on...**

now one solution can be, calling list.removeAll() before appending the data in TableViewController but I don't want to get the data again and again when there are no changes in the data. so is there a way?

Comment: First of all show your code. Second of all probably you add the data in `viewWillAppear`. Move it to `viewDidLoad`

Comment: okay, I think that was the problem.  thanks!! but why does adding data in viewWillAppear cause this issue?

Comment: Because – as the name implies – `viewWillAppear` is always called when the view is going to appear. Unlike `viewWillDisappear` which is called in the top view controller before being popped.